# How to fix button which is not linked to the function used for sorting data? (javascript only, no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a sort button of a certain data so that I could sort them ascending, but there is an error inside the coding, where do I need to start? thank you

```js
var planetsObj = [{
    name: "Alderaan",
    rotation_period: 24,
    orbital_period: 364
  },
  {
    name: "Yavin IV",
    rotation_period: 24,
    orbital_period: 4818
  },
  {
    name: "Hoth",
    rotation_period: 23,
    orbital_period: 549
  },
  {
    name: "Dagobah",
    rotation_period: 23,
    orbital_period: 341
  },
  {
    name: "Bespin",
    rotation_period: 12,
    orbital_period: 5110
  }
]

var sortID = function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
planetsObj.sort(sortID);

window.onload = function compare() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = sortID;
}
text = ''
    for(var i=0;i<planetsObj.length;i++){
        console.log(planetsObj[i])
        name = planetsObj[i].name;
        text += '<div>' +name+ '</div>';
    }
    document.querySelector('div#tbody').innerHTML = text
    
    text = '';
    for(var i=0;i<planetsObj.length;i++){
        console.log(planetsObj[i])
        rotation_period= planetsObj[i].rotation_period;
        text += '<div>' +rotation_period+ '</div>';
    }
    document.querySelector('div#yes').innerHTML = text

    text = '';
    for(var i=0;i<planetsObj.length;i++){
        console.log(planetsObj[i])
        orbital_period= planetsObj[i].orbital_period;
        text += '<div>' +orbital_period+ '</div>';
    }
    document.querySelector('div#no').innerHTML = text





    </script>
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Click the button to sort the table alphabetically, by name:</p>
  <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="sort by name">

  <Table class="rTable">
    <div id="tbody"></div>
    <div id="yes"></div>
    <div id="no"></div>
  </Table>
```

I expect that everytime I click the button the data will be sorted ascending, sorry if the question is too basic, because I'm still beginner, thank you very much

Comment: You can't put `<div>` elements directly in `<table>`. It can only contain `<tr>` elements (or `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and `<tfoot>`, which contain the rows).

Comment: What are you trying to sort when you click the button? There's nothing in the table.

Comment: If you want to sort the array, you need to do `planetsObj.sort(sortID)` in the `onclick` function. `sortID` is just the comparison function, it doesn't actually sort anything.

Comment: https://codepen.io/evenstensberg/pen/MROqNR

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much sir, I will fix the <table>, I'm sorry I didn't put the full javascript but I already edit it with the full coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a method to call sort function and add to event `addEventListener('click', sort);`

```
function sort(){
planetsObj.sort(sortID);
console.log(planetsObj);
}
window.onload = function compare() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', sort);
}
```

Updated: update for display list object in table using javascript.

```js
var planetsObj = [{
    name: "Alderaan",
    rotation_period: 24,
    orbital_period: 364
  },
  {
    name: "Yavin IV",
    rotation_period: 24,
    orbital_period: 4818
  },
  {
    name: "Hoth",
    rotation_period: 23,
    orbital_period: 549
  },
  {
    name: "Dagobah",
    rotation_period: 23,
    orbital_period: 341
  },
  {
    name: "Bespin",
    rotation_period: 12,
    orbital_period: 5110
  }
]

var sortID = function compare(a, b) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return 1;
  
  return 0;
}
function sort(){
planetsObj.sort(sortID);
//console.log(planetsObj);
var tableRef = document.getElementById('rTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
for(var i= 0; i < planetsObj.length; i++){
// Insert a row in the table at the last row
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
// Append a text node to the cell
var newText  = document.createTextNode(planetsObj[i].name);
newCell.appendChild(newText);
var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText2  = document.createTextNode(planetsObj[i].rotation_period);

newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
var newCell3  = newRow.insertCell(2);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText3  = document.createTextNode(planetsObj[i].orbital_period);

newCell3.appendChild(newText3);
}
}
window.onload = function compare() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', sort);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Click the button to sort the table alphabetically, by name:</p>
  <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="sort by name">

  <table border="1" class="rTable" id="rTable">
      <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>rotation_period</th>
      <th>orbital_period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I miss the addEventListener event, I will try to edit my home work

Comment: I tried your answer and it worked, I would like to ask on how to rearrange the divs so that not only console that are sorted, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorting can be implemented in your case by sorting the objects and reBuilding the table.

Below code on click of button will sort the planets object and rebuild the sorted table.

To Make sort generic based on any column, Please remodify the sort logic and create a on Click event on basis of table header.

Please find below sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script>
        var planetsObj = [
        {
        name: "Alderaan", 
        rotation_period: 24, 
        orbital_period: 364
        },
        {
        name: "Yavin IV", 
        rotation_period: 24, 
        orbital_period: 4818
        },
        {
        name: "Hoth", 
        rotation_period: 23, 
        orbital_period: 549
        },
        {
        name: "Dagobah", 
        rotation_period: 23, 
        orbital_period: 341
        },
        {
        name: "Bespin", 
        rotation_period: 12, 
        orbital_period: 5110
        }
    ]
        var planetLabels = ['name', 'rotation_period','orbital_period']; 




        var sortID = function compare(a,b) {
        if (a.name < b.name)
            return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name)
            return 1;
        return 0;
        }

        function sortRows(){
            planetsObj.sort(sortID);
            buildTable(planetLabels, planetsObj, document.getElementById('rTable'));
        }


        window.onload = function compare() {
            buildTable(planetLabels, planetsObj, document.getElementById('rTable'));
        }

        document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = sortRows();

        function buildTable(labels, objects, tableObj) {
              var thead = document.createElement('thead');
              var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
          var theadTr = document.createElement('tr');
          for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            var theadTh = document.createElement('th');
            theadTh.innerHTML = labels[i];
            theadTr.appendChild(theadTh);
          }
          thead.appendChild(theadTr);
          tableObj.appendChild(thead);

          for (j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
            var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (k = 0; k < labels.length; k++) {
              var tbodyTd = document.createElement('td');
              tbodyTd.innerHTML = objects[j][labels[k].toLowerCase()];
              tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTd);
            }
            tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
          }
          tableObj.appendChild(tbody);


        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
      <p>Click the button to sort the table alphabetically, by name:</p>
      <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="sort by name">

        <table class="rTable" id="rTable">

        </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try to edit my homework

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the array when you click the button, you have to write a function that does that, and use it in the `onclick` function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function() {
    planetsObj.sort(sortID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your help, I will try to edit my homework